# Can't connect to the local MongoDB server running on localhost:27017 from my express application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I can't connect to the local mongodb server running on localhost:27017 from my express application. I'm pretty sure that I haven't done anything wrong in the code I wrote as I've copied it from a tutorial. The code worked fine on that tutorial. And I've also made sure that the mongodb service is running. I've already created a database called "blog" from mongosh shell and inserted some data to a collection called "authors" on it. I've also installed the MongoDB Node Driver using "npm install mongodb" command. But whenever I try to run npm start, this error shows up and I can't run my application thereafter.

```
E:\My-Coding-Projects\Current Projects\28-web-100-nodejs-mongodb-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:306
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\My-Coding-Projects\Current Projects\28-web-100-nodejs-mongodb-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:306:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 195900556,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\My-Coding-Projects\Current Projects\28-web-100-nodejs-mongodb-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:382:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\My-Coding-Projects\Current Projects\28-web-100-nodejs-mongodb-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the code I wrote on database.js to create the connection to the local mongodb server.

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let database;

async function connect() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  database = client.db("blog");
}

function getDb() {
  if (!database) {
    throw { message: "Database connection not established!" };
  }
  return database;
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase: connect,
  getDb: getDb,
};
```

This is the code I wrote on app.js to connect the database to it and run the application.

```
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");

const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const db = require("./data/database");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(blogRoutes);

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).render("500");
});

db.connectToDatabase().then(function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?

Comment: Yes. The MongoDB service was running on the background for the whole time. I've also kept Mongosh shell open and kept connected to the blog database from that to.